# Cannot provide permission to IIS_IUSRS on C:/Windows/Temp

Tags: windows-7, iis-7, user-permissions

I have an ASP.NET Web Forms Application which has some reports created using SAP Crystal Reports Runtime for .NET Framework 4. The `C:\Windows\Temp` folder contains my Report files of the application. That's why, I need to provide `IIS_IUSRS` permission on `C:\Windows\Temp`.

Problem is, whenever I'm trying to give `IIS_IUSRS` permission to Temp, I'm getting this error message:

```
Error Applying Security


An error occured while applying security information to


C:\Windows\Temp


Access is Denied
```

If I click on the option 'Continue', I get the following error:

```
Windows Security


Unable to save permission changes on Temp

Access is denied
```

I need urgent solution to this because I have an emergency delivery. At any cost, I **MUST** have to grant `IIS_IUSRS` access to `C:\Windows\Temp`. Please help urgently.

.NET Framework - 4, IIS - 7, Windows 7 Ultimate - 64 bit.

Comment: How do you set the permissions, Windows Explorer? or elevelated command prompt and icacls.exe?  I also suggest running `chkdsk` on your C: drive.

Comment: Windows Explorer.

Comment: Open `cmd.exe` as administrator and run `icacls.exe C:\Windows\Temp /grant "BUILTIN\IIS_IUSRS:(OI)(CI)(M)"` what do you get?

Comment: @PeterHahndorf I'm currently engaged in another task. I'll let you know once I get back to this issue. Thanks very much. :)

Answer (score 0):

**How I Solved the Problem** 
 1. Run **cmd as admin** (keep it open ).
 2. Open task manager and  **kill explorer.exe.** 
 3. Go to previously opened CMD. Type `explorer.exe` and hit enter. 
 4. Navigate to c:\windows\temp (right click) -> properties -> security  
 5. Now you will be able to change  \IIS_IUSRS to Full Control

**Edit:** Some applications may give an error about elevated explorer.exe . It will be fixed after restart.

**If you don’t want to restart: Take explorer.exe out of Administrator mode;**
1. Go to previosly opened task manager.  Kill explorer.exe  
2. In task manager file -> start new process  write there explorer.exe 
 
3. Now the  explorer.exe is in normal mode.